# When do I use org.springframework.format.Printer interface?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When I use spring-mvc, I always use spring formatter to format a string to Java Bean. So, I implement `org.springframework.format.Formatter` interface.
Despite I implement two methods(`print()`,`parse()`), the `print` method has never been used. Because I just use `parse()`method format a String to Java Bean and never format Java Bean to String.
So, my question is, what situation does the `print()` will be called? Or when I need format a Java Bean to String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatters can be used for parsing and printing *Dates*, *Timestamps*, and **general numeric data**.

This means, as you already pointed out, that we can customize the way parsing is handled for a specific type by overriding the *parse()* method.

**It also means that we can provide custom print behaviour by overriding the *print()* method.**

**So, what's print's use case?**
Let's put an example.

Suppose you have a serial number type composed of 4 segments —e.g., 1111-2222-3333-4444.

```
public class SerialNumber {

  private int segment1;
  private int segment2;
  private int segment3;
  private int segment4;

  //Some getters and setters;

}
```

Now, we'll implement a Formatter class that can parse an input like the one shown above. For brevity's sake I'll avoid try-catch blocks and validation logic:

```
public class SerialNumberFormatter implements Formatter {

  public SerialNumber parse(String input, Locale locale) {

     //Some code here to validate input

     //Split the input into segments
     String[] result = speech.split("-");

     return new SerialNumber(Integer.parseInt(result[0],
                             Integer.parseInt(result[1],
                             Integer.parseInt(result[2],
                             Integer.parseInt(result[3])

  }

}
```

So, this way we managed to parse the Serial Number. But we already knew this. **Now, let's suppose we'd like to show a SerialNumber stored in our DB to the end-user in the following format "SN: 1111-2222-3333-4444".** We need to print the object somehow. That logic can be implemented inside the print() method.

Completing our Formatter class:

```
public class SerialNumberFormatter implements Formatter {

  public SerialNumber parse(String input, Locale locale) {

     //Some code here to validate input

     //Split the input into segments
     String[] result = speech.split("-");

     return new SerialNumber(Integer.parseInt(result[0],
                             Integer.parseInt(result[1],
                             Integer.parseInt(result[2],
                             Integer.parseInt(result[3])

  }
  public String print(SerialNumber sn, Locale locale) {

     //Some code here to validate the sn

     return String.format("SN: %d-%d-&d-%d", sn.getSegment1,
                                      sn.getSegment2,
                                      sn.getSegment3,
                                      sn.getSegment4)
  }

}
```

To sum up, *Formatter* allows us to encapsulate logic related to parsing and printing, that otherwise would need to be coded into a business or service layer.

Remember that a Formatter can also be composed of Parser and Printer classes. So, a *print()* method may contain printing logic much more complicated than just building a String. It could encapsulate logic to format a POJO and write it to a file. It could also return a JSON or an XML as output.

Take it mainly as an abstraction that lets us decouple formatting logic from the rest of our code.

**Formatter interface is also a core piece of the Spring Framework. You can implement custom Formatters and then register them into the framework for different tasks.** You can take a look at this Baeldung's article: https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc

In Section 8, you'll appreciatte how a Formatter is implement and then registered to Spring MVC to convert and show data in the front-end.

Comment: It seems that `print()` can be replaced with `toString()` method.

Comment: Not really. ToString is meant to provide basic conversión of a POJO, while Formatter intends to encapsulate complex logic that's not responsibility of the POJO. If your print method were to format the pojo into am xml compliant with an xsd, you would need code that wouldnt just be a string concatenation. And it would be wrong to put al that code inside toString. Also, there are the Spring use cases that Ive mentioned at the end of the response which are very important.